# " Can you explain and give some examples of it's usage "

Tags: meaning-in-context, sentence-meaning

Can you help me with learning this phrase

[image: Unseen phrase for me]

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. First, please take the time to type out the pertinent sections, as images  do not scan. Then do a minimum of research into the usage. Finally, clarify what it is exactly that you do not understand. It seems clear. _Through_ in this case means "over and done with".

Comment: I'm finding it difficult to find this precise usage (be through eating/working/moaning etc) in dictionary examples, though most give 'be through with' ('Are you through with the hairdrier yet?' = 'Have you finished using the hairdrier yet?') 'He thought I was through eating my dinner' is informal, mainly US, and means 'He thought I had finished eating my dinner'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example it refers to connotation a:

***[be through (with somebody/something)](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/be-through-with-somebody-something)***
informal

> a) to have finished doing something or using something
> *I’m not through just yet – I should be finished in an hour.
> Are you through with the computer yet?*

> b) to no longer be having a relationship with someone
> *That’s it! Simon and I are through.
> I’m through with you!*

(Longman Dictionary)

Comment: As I commented, dictionaries seem reluctant to give examples of the form "Are you through eating your dinner?" with an ing-form. The two grammatical usages you give (intransitive, and with transitivising 'with', should have been found by OP.

Comment: Thank you so much , your answers are what I ve been looking for